# java regex - find all elements

Tags: java, regex

I have the content as a string:

```
{1:F01[some data there]}{2:I515[some data there]}{4::[multiple data there]}{5:{TNG:}}
{1:F01[some data there]}{2:I515[some data there]}{4::[multiple data there too]}{5:{TNG:}}
{1:F01[some data there]}{2:I515[some data there]}{4::[some data there]}{5:{TNG:}}
```

I want to find every record. A record starts with {1} and ends with {5}.
I already wrote this regex:

```
(\{1:F01)?.*(\{2:)?.*(\{5:\{TNG:\}\})?
```

But i always get the whole content containing every record.
What to do?

Comment: Because `{1` and `{5` are made optional with `?`

Comment: Are you looking to _match_ certain records, or are you looking to _extract_ a potion of matching records?

Comment: Use a simpler [`\{1:F01.*?\{5:\{TNG:}}`](https://regex101.com/r/1UOf1X/2).

Comment: I want to use matcher and a get 3 records using group. Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot use a [repeated capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) with Java regex. You have two more or less working answers below that should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, it will match as long as possible, and might glob too many records.

`.*?` will stop as soon as possible.

This should do:

```
\{1:.*?\{5:\{TNG:\}\}
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex matches every like because `{1` and `{5` are made optional with `?`, and the `.*` will try to match everything

You can use a simple regex like,

```
/^\{1:F01.*5:\{TNG:\}\}$/gm
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dbVbbV/2)

---

**Regex Explanation**

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `{1:F01.*` Matches `{1:F01` at the start of the string, followed by anything.
- `5:\{TNG:\}\}` Matches at the end of the string.
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string.

**Edit**

In java, the multiline is added using `Pattern.MULTILINE`. If your input string is not multiline, you need not add this flag at all.

Also the regex need not be delimited by `//`.

**Example**

```
String s="{1:F01[some data there]}{2:I515[some data there]}{4::[some data there]}{5:{TNG:}}";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^\\{1:F01.*5:\\{TNG:\\}\\}$", Pattern.MULTILINE); 
Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.matches());
// true
```

Comment: You probably need an `m` modifier.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer How is you input string? If it is multi line input, You have to use `gm` flags

Comment: copied it from op

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: `String s="{1:F01[some data there]}{2:I515[some data there]}{4::[some data there]}{5:{TNG:}}";
  Pattern p=Pattern.compile("/^\\{1:F01.*5:\\{TNG:\\}\\}$/gm");
  Matcher m=p.matcher(s);`  this is false if i print m.matches()

Comment: You need `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\{1:F01.*5:\\{TNG:\\}\\}$");`

Comment: `/regex/gm` is just a syntax to show that it is a regex with two flags, g and m. You shouldn't write the `/` inside the regex when using Java.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have added an edit on why it is not working. Hope it helps

Comment: the first `/` in your first regex seemed to be the problem. now it works finde

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Both the `//` are a problem. That is how you delimit regex string in normal *regex syntax*. But it varies with programming language. As in java you don't need to have any delimiters.

Comment: ah okay didn't know about regex syntax. only know java code